# Showing a div on mouseover

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I've got a bunch of nested divs, ul's etc. Structure is shown here.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#top-level').mouseover( function() {
        $( this ).find('.action').show();
        $( this ).find('.drop').show('slide');
    });
    $('#top-level').mouseout( function(){
        $( this ).find('.drop').hide('blind', function(){
            $('.action').hide();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="top-level">
    <div>
        <div class="action" style="display:none;">
            <ul class="drop" style="display:none;">
                <li>Text Here</li>
                <li>Text Here</li>
                <li>Text Here</li>
            </ul>       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ul shown here is being shown on a rollover. The .drop css is set as position:absolute so that it appears over the top-level div.

So, the ul drop appears nicely but as soon as it come in contact with the mouse cursor it goes mad (blinds up and down non stop etc)! Now this will have something to do with the mouse over losing focus in some way.

For this sort of effect to work properly how should I go about it? I want to be able to scroll over the div and chose options from the drop ul after it appears.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/PDdKL/

Use hover instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#top-level').hover( function() {
        $( this ).find('.action').show();
        $( this ).find('.drop').show('slide');
    }, function(){
        $( this ).find('.drop').hide('blind', function(){
            $('.action').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works much better now. Trouble is, I have a number of these top-level divs. Works fine if I carefully move over each one now, however at speed the effect fails and nothing appears. Could this be something to do with propagation?

Comment: If you have multiple top-level div's I hope they have different ID's? But that's not your question. I'm not really sure what you're asking though. If you're moving the mouse too quickly, then you've probably caused the hide() before the show() had a chance. But if you clarify I could probably help more.

Comment: Yes they do - I'm just showing a simple framework above. It seems that if I move the the mouse over with little haste the effect works fine for each div but when moved across the div's with a little momentum the effect has trouble rendering to the point where the effect fails altogether. Leave it for a moment and it starts to work again. As you said it is something to do with the hide/show. Thank you, by the way.

Comment: I would like to keep the mouseleave (hover out) effect and have the next div effect start as the last div is finishing its out effect and so on.

Comment: Instead of using the find method I now explicitly get the unique id that refers to the div id, ul id etc. This fixes all my effect problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use mouseenter and mouseleave.

```
    $('#top-level').mouseenter( function() {
        $( this ).find('.action').show();
        $( this ).find('.drop').show('slide');
    });
    $('#top-level').mouseleave( function(){
        $( this ).find('.drop').hide('blind', function(){
            $('.action').hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks - it gives me a similar effect as hover. But the same as hover, as I scroll over each top-level div the effect appears and then disappears within a second or so when moving the mouse with purpose. Something is effecting it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(element).stop();` in the beginning of every event handler to stop animations on that element.

Answer (score 0):

I made something like this for someone check it out here;

http://jsfiddle.net/RyanAdriano/AWm66/8/